# E > E:nth-child(2) pattern doesn't work. How to solve it?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I have a structure:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div> <!-- first div -->
        <div>  <!-- second div -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to apply styles to the **first** and to the **second** divs using `E > E:nth-child(n)` pattern. But it doesn't work for the **second** div, only for the **first** one.

```
/* this works */
#outer > div:nth-child(1) {
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 10px;
}

/* this doesn't work */
#outer > div:nth-child(2) {
    border: 1px solid green;
    padding: 10px
}
```

Why doesn't work? How can I make it work?

Comment: That's because each inner `div` is the first and only child of its parent `div`...

Comment: Because the second div is not a child of #outer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second div is not a direct child from `#outer`. So your selector `#outer > div` does not affect the second div as `>` only selects **direct** children.
Maybe you could use

```
/* this works */
#outer > div:nth-child(1) {
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 10px;
}

/* this should also work */
#outer > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) {
    border: 1px solid green;
    padding: 10px
}
```

Comment: It's not only the `>` selector but also the `:nth-child()` selector. Maybe if they called it `:nth-direct-child()` instead...

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Now I see the difference.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one :

```
#outer > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1)
```

Comment: Thank you, yes, this works. `#outer > div > div` works and `#outer > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1)` works too.

Comment: I deleted the old one because it didn't match to your pattern you've mentioned. Good luck !